# PySpark explode date range into rows

Tags: python, pyspark, row, explode, date-range

I need to explode date range into multiple rows with new start and end dates so the exploded rows have a range of one day only. I also need a new unique userId and need to retain start times and end times.

Input dataframe

| userId | Start_Date_Time | End_Date_Time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 2022-12-10 08:00:00 | 2022-12-15 17:00:00 |
| b | 2022-12-06 05:00:00 | 2022-12-07 18:00:00 |

Desired Output:

| userId | userIdNew | Start_Date_Time | End_Date_Time | Start_Date_Time_New | End_Date_Time_New |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | a1 | 2022-12-10 08:00:00 | 2022-12-15 17:00:00 | 2022-12-10 08:00:00 | 2022-12-11 17:00:00 |
| a | a2 | 2022-12-10 08:00:00 | 2022-12-15 17:00:00 | 2022-12-11 08:00:00 | 2022-12-12 17:00:00 |
| a | a3 | 2022-12-10 08:00:00 | 2022-12-15 17:00:00 | 2022-12-12 08:00:00 | 2022-12-13 17:00:00 |
| a | a4 | 2022-12-10 08:00:00 | 2022-12-15 17:00:00 | 2022-12-13 08:00:00 | 2022-12-14 17:00:00 |
| a | a5 | 2022-12-10 08:00:00 | 2022-12-15 17:00:00 | 2022-12-14 08:00:00 | 2022-12-15 17:00:00 |
| b | b1 | 2022-12-06 05:00:00 | 2022-12-07 18:00:00 | 2022-12-06 05:00:00 | 2022-12-07 18:00:00 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'F.sequence' function will make an array of values between two given columns. because it will include the last value too ([1, 3] -> [1, 2, 3]) you need to reduce endDate by 1 day. after exploding the array you have your start dates and by adding 1 day to it you can have end dates too. for new user id you can use row_number and contacting it with previous id.

```
from pyspark.sql import Window as W
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
(
    df
    .withColumn('startDate', F.col('startDate').astype('date'))
    .withColumn('endDate', F.col('endDate').astype('date'))
    .withColumn(
        'timeseries', 
        F.sequence(
            F.col('startDate'), 
            F.date_add(F.col('endDate'), -1), 
            F.expr("INTERVAL 1 DAY")))
    .select(
        F.col('id'),
        F.col('startDate'),
        F.col('endDate'),
        F.explode('timeseries').alias('newStartDate'),)
    .withColumn('newEndDate', F.date_add(F.col('newStartDate'), 1))
    .withColumn('rowNumber', F.row_number().over(W.partitionBy('id').orderBy('newStartDate')))
    .withColumn('newId', F.concat('id', 'rowNumber'))
    .drop('rowNumber')
).show()
```