# Generating weekly date column from two dates columns

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataset which has multiple column, the columns that I'm interested in are below

```
ID  start_date  end_date
1   1999-04-07  2013-09-15
1   2015-08-15  2017-02-01
2   2018-05-04  2020-04-02
8   2000-01-03  2011-07-19
```

[image]

I would like to create a new column called weekly_end_date generating weekly end date between start and end date columns.
Something like below in PySpark

```
ID  start_date  end_date    Weekly_end_date
1   1999-04-07  2013-09-15  1999-04-13
1   1999-04-07  2013-09-15  1999-04-20
1   1999-04-07  2013-09-15  1999-04-27
1   1999-04-07  2013-09-15  2013-09-15 <--Until it gets here, It should stop from here
    2015-08-15  2017-02-01  2015-08-22 <-- It should start again from here
    2018-05-04  2020-04-02                      
    2000-01-03  2011-07-19
```

[image]

I've tried this code, but it does not generate all dates between start and end date columns. And it stops after generating the first start and end dates

```
df = df.withColumn("weekly_end_date ", 
                   explode(sequence('start_date', 'end_date', interval 1 week)))
```

Comment: can you please refer to the link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74857559/pyspark-explode-date-range-into-rows.I think i this has been answered before . Please do let me know if it does not get resolved

Comment: Thanks Avind! That question in the link for sequence of 1 day, but mine is for sequence of 7 days. I'll try to adjust it and see if it works.

Comment: @Avind I've tried that answer and it works but when I try df.show() it gives me an error of stage failure.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, explode, sequence

spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local[1]").appName('SparkByExamples.com').getOrCreate()

data = [(1, "1999-04-07", "2013-09-15"),
        (1, "2015-08-15", "2017-02-01"),
        (2, "2018-05-04", "2020-04-02"),
        (8, "2000-01-03", "2011-07-19")]

columns = ["ID", "start_date", "end_date"]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, columns)

df = df.withColumn("start_date", col("start_date").cast("date"))
df = df.withColumn("end_date", col("end_date").cast("date"))

df = df.withColumn("weekly_end_date", explode(sequence("start_date", "end_date", expr("interval 1 week"))))

df.show(truncate=False)
```